# Bounded set in finite normed vector space

Tags: general-topology

Let $E$ be a finite-dimensional normed vector space and $A$ a non-empty and bounded subset of $E$.
Let $I = \{R\geq 0: \exists \mathcal{B}_{F}(x, R), A \subset \mathcal{B}_{F}(x, R)\}$, and $r=\inf I$.

Let $R_n = r+\frac{1}{n}$. Show that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, there exists $x_n \in E$ such that $A \subset \mathcal{B}_F(x_n, R_n)$.

Comment: When you say finite, do you mean finite dimensional?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur yes!

Comment: The finite-dimensionality of $E$ plays no role in this proof BTW.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma That's what I realized now. I  was misled i was trying to find an argument that involved the compactness of the closed balls.

Comment: Maybe that’ll be later, when they take a convergent subsequence of the $(x_n)$ by compactness later in the argument (assuming this is the first part of some larger proof).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma You're right haha. I've just used this argument to prove the existence of a convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r+\frac1n > r = \inf I$ we have that $r+\frac1n$ is **not** a lower bound for $I$, or $\inf I$ would not be the *largest* lower bound of $I$. So **some** $R_n \in I$ obeys $R_n < r+\frac1n$, and by the definition of $I$ this means there is some $x_n$ such that $A \subseteq B(x_n, R_n)\subseteq B(x_n, r + \frac1n)$ for this $R_n$. Done.

Answer (score 2):

Your $I$ has the following property: if $s\in I$ and $t>s$ then $t\in I$. Therefore $I$ is an interval, more precisely either $(r,\infty)$ or $[r,\infty)$. Regardless, $r+\epsilon$ is always in $I$ for any $\epsilon>0$. Which, by the definition of $I$, means that there is $x\in e$ such that $A\subseteq B(x,r+\epsilon)$.

Comment: Do you think it is enough to justify the existence of $x_n$ ?

Comment: @RFTexas You should probably try to phrase the meaning of $\inf I=r$ with the sequence $r+\frac{1}{n}$, and then use freakish's answer to conclude.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur so something like this: r is the radius of the smallest ball that contains A.  Therefore, for any $\epsilon > 0$, r + $\epsilon \in I$, which implies there exists a corresponding center $x_n$.

Comment: @RFTexas as I said $r+\epsilon\in I$. And so by the definition of $I$ there is $x\in E$ such that $A\subseteq B(x, r+\epsilon)$.

Comment: Understood ! Thanks!